# Extending Keycloak theme

Tags: themes, keycloak

I would like to create a custom theme for keycloak for replacing some user-facing pages with a different style.
The keycloak manual describes this process of [Creating a Theme](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#creating-a-theme) and recommends to derive a custom theme from an existing one.

For doing that, the docs reference in the [Theme Properties](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#theme-properties) this properties:

- parent - Parent theme to extend
- import - Import resources from another theme

with an example of

```
parent=base
import=common/keycloak
```

Unfortunately, the docs do not describe how that theme-extension does actually work (or I don't get it...).

Does the "parent=base" automatically use all files from that theme and just overlays those from the new theme?

What does the "import=common/keycloak" reference? I can't find any component or file path in the base theme where that would match.

Answer (score 5):

If any of you is interested, I created a theme builder that let you extend the default Keycloak theme... or create a new one from scratch.
Example:

[image]

Checkout [Keycloakify](https://github.com/garronej/keycloakify)

Answer (score 3):

When you say `parent=base` you are extending the base theme.

In your `theme.properties` the `import=common/keycloak` imports all the resources from `keycloak` theme of type `common`

you can find resources in `<KEYCLOAK-HOME>/themes/keycloak/common`

Comment: Hmm... so the syntax for "import" is always "{type_component}/{theme_name}"? And it's primary purpose is then to integrate components of **other** themes, which are not contained in the parent theme...? So, using for example "parent=keycloak" would not require the mentioned import, because the "common" component would already be included?

Comment: yes it should include common, but not tried extending keycloak theme

Answer (score 2):

I had to deal with a similar issue where I had to extend multiple themes from a base theme (`shared-base-theme`).

Folder structure:

```
keycloak_theme/
  login/
    themes/
      shared-base-theme/
        messages/
          messages_en.properties
        resources/
          css/
            login.css
          fonts/
            font1.eot
            font1.otf
          img/
            background.png
        theme.properties
      theme1/
        ...
      theme2/
        ...
```

To make sure `theme1` and `theme2` extend my `shared-base-theme`, I had to update their respective `theme.properties` files.
E.g. for `theme1` it would look like this:

```
parent=shared-base-theme
styles=css/login.css css/custom.css
```

where `css/login.css` is the one from the `shared-base-theme` `resources/css` directory and `css/custom.css` is located in the `resources/css` folder of `theme1`.
I.e. it will apply the shared `login.css` and custom styles on top of it can be specified in `custom.css`.

If you simply wanted to import styles (instead of extending the base) from the `shared-base-theme` you could instead specify something like:

```
parent=base
import=login/shared-base-theme
styles=css/login.css css/custom.css
```

I hope this will help someone else as well.